# Sublime's object outline (CTRL + R) don't show Javascript class methods made with arrow functions

Tags: sublimetext3

In Sublime Text I can't see [by CTRL+R] Javascript class methods made by "property initializer" `method = () => {}`  style, but only "canonical" `method(){}` style is showing, it's very confusing.

I'm using Sublime Text3 build 3126, Linux.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you perhaps using a third party JS syntax definition? It seems to work out of the box in build 3126.

Comment: @Keith Hall no, any whistles, just plain javascript standalone and in react apps. Just now , suddenly apears, that if `;` present after closing `}` of method (what, is told, is nesessary in this case) -- method isn't appear in list. if `;` is removed -- its all ok.   sad.